# Using Font Awesome in Vue3 with Bulma

Tags: html, vue.js, font-awesome, vuejs3, bulma

How should Font Awesome be used with Vue? I have [vue-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#the-icon-property) added to my project, as well as [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/icon/), so am I supposed to intermix the two? Or choose one or the other? I would like to be able to use Bulma's classes for coloring the icons.

[Vue-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#the-icon-property) shows using this syntax:

```html
<font-awesome-icon icon="address-card" />
```

and [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/icon/) shows using this syntax:

```html
<span class="icon">
  <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
</span>
```

Questions:

1. If I am supposed to intermix the two, how should the html syntax look?
2. If I can only choose one or the other, what would be the limitations of each?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? If so: Answering your own question would be useful for others with the same issue. If not: Maybe consider showing a little bit of your attempts and possible error messages etc.

Answer (score 1):

`<font-awesome-icon>` is just a convenience component. When you check your resulting HTML, you will find it renders `<i class="fas fa-home"></i>`.

The above statement is of course really simplified. In my projects I am using the SVG icons, so `<font-awesome-icon>` will render as `<svg>...</svg>`.

Bulma's HTML provides a container to put an arbitrary icon into it. That can be Font Awesome, but it can also be something else. It just provides the layout.

With that in mind, I would answer your questions:

1. Just put the icon (Font Awesome) into the container (Bulma)

```html
<span class="icon">
  <font-awesome-icon icon="address-card" />
</span>
```

To color the icon, Bulma's helpers work just fine:

```html
<span class="icon has-text-danger">
  <font-awesome-icon icon="exclamation" />
</span>
```

2. Does not apply, since both of them serve different purposes and complement each other.

Answer (score -1):

Install [Font Awesome package](http://Install%20Font%20Awesome%20package)

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Then load its CSS files

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'
```

Example loading it globally

```
// Vue.js 3
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import "bulma/bulma.sass"
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Its is an Vue 3 example, but should work the same way on Vue 2 apps if the same steps are followed.

Comment: OP is asking different questions.